# using multiple intent in an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 6 page that page 1-5  on a button click sends an string to page 6 and page 6 shows them in textviews using intent
but when i reach page 6 it shows only the last string in all of textviews

page 1

```
public class page1 extends ActionBarActivity {


public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);



}


public void cow (View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, page2.class));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, resault.class);
    String message = "پیشرو بودن";
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

}
public void horse (View view){

    startActivity(new Intent(this, page2.class));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, resault.class);
    String message = "خانواده";
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
public void pig (View view){

    startActivity(new Intent(this, page2.class));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, resault.class);
    String message = "پول";
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
public void tiger (View view){

    startActivity(new Intent(this, page2.class));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, resault.class);
    String message = "غرور و افتخار";
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
public void sheep (View view){

    startActivity(new Intent(this, page2.class));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, resault.class);
    String message = "عشق";
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}

}
```

to page 4 its the same but i changed the numbers

page5

```
public class page5 extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE5="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page5);
}


public void cow (View view){
    Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, resault.class);
    String message5 = "پیشرو بودن";
    intent5.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE5, message5);
    startActivity(intent5);
}

public void horse (View view){
    Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, resault.class);
    String message5 = "خانواده";
    intent5.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE5, message5);
    startActivity(intent5);
}

public void pig (View view){
    Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, resault.class);
    String message5 = "پول";
    intent5.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE5, message5);
    startActivity(intent5);
}

public void tiger (View view){
    Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, resault.class);
    String message5 = "غرور و افتخار";
    intent5.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE5, message5);
    startActivity(intent5);
}

public void sheep (View view){


    Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, resault.class);
    String message5 = "عشق";
    intent5.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE5, message5);
    startActivity(intent5);
}


}
```

receiver page (page 6)

```
public class resault extends ActionBarActivity {


TextView ch1;
TextView ch2;
TextView ch3;
TextView ch4;
TextView ch5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resault);







    // choise1

    ch1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    Intent intent;
    intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(page1.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    ch1.setText(message);

    // choise2

    ch2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    Intent intent2;
    intent2 = getIntent();
    String message2 = intent2.getStringExtra(page2.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);
    ch2.setText(message2);


    // choise3

    ch3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice3);
    Intent intent3;
    intent3 = getIntent();
    String message3 = intent3.getStringExtra(page3.EXTRA_MESSAGE3);
    ch3.setText(message3);

    // choise4

    ch4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice4);
    Intent intent4;
    intent4 = getIntent();
    String message4 = intent4.getStringExtra(page4.EXTRA_MESSAGE4);
    ch4.setText(message4);


    // choise5

    ch5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice5);
    Intent intent5;
    intent5 = getIntent();
    String message5 = intent5.getStringExtra(page5.EXTRA_MESSAGE5);
    ch5.setText(message5);


}




}
```

really really thank you for helping

Comment: You calling to the same Intent every time:

    getIntent();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your logic. For example in page 6:

```
public class resault extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MASSAGE = "massage";
    public final static String EXTRA_PAGE = "page";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resault);
        String text = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MASSAGE);
        if (text != null ) {
            int page = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_PAGE, -1);
            switch (page) {
                case 1:
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice1)).setText(text);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice2)).setText(text);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice3)).setText(text);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice4)).setText(text);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice5)).setText(text);
                    break;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then you do in page 3 for example:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, resault.class);
    String message = "خانواده";
    intent.putExtra(Result.EXTRA_PAGE, 3);
    intent.putExtra(Result.EXTRA_MASSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: sorry that is ask again :p , i need to get resault from all of 5 pages to resault and not just one of them , but with this code it just shows one and when i use <startActivity(new Intent(this, page4.class));> to get to page 4 on case 3 so i can get resault from page 4 it closes the resault page and case 3 data will be erased , how can i keep resault activity open to get back to it?

Comment: Do you want to move from page to page and finally to the Result page will all the Data?Anyway id you want to save the data in the Result page you need to save it in Bundle when activity destroied. Read here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: yes it need to move from page to page , and finally show the resault if all 5 pages together in resault page

Comment: i am reading it and trying to use that , but its not working , sorry for not understanding :p im very new to android

Comment: Look, you new to android and it OK. if you tried and it not work for you, you can open new question, with the relevant code only, that you explain what you tried to do and what not worked..